# The requested module 'node:util' does not provide an export named 'parseArgs'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-server

When I write the command line "json-server -w" to check the version of json but the error appears.
How can I fix that error?
The version of nodejs is 16.16.0.
Please help me find the problem and solution. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From Nodejs API Docs, [`util.parseArgs([config])`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilparseargsconfig) was implemented in Nodejs version `v18.3.0, v16.17.0` or above.

Since yours is `16.16.0` its not available, so update it to new version.

Note: It also mentions

> v20.0.0: The API is no longer experimental

So I encourage you to install nodejs version v20 or above